# RegEx that should allow only special chars and not any alphanumeric chars from keyboard

Tags: c#, regex

I have requirement of text box which should allow special chars and not any alpha numeric strings.

So I want to use a RegEx that should allow only special chars.

-Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far by yourself?

Comment: Questions that don't show any research effort may be down voted.

Comment: @sanjayThorat you need to show a little bit of an effort here.. this is not a code factory site..

Comment: Look at me... I'm a `.` (dot)... Now I'm a "special" character... Will I receive "special" treatment? :)

Comment: Hay hi all "Genius" thanks for the great welcome.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Only non word characters, 0 or more times

```
^\W*$
```

Look at very simple Quick Reference at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks cypizek this is what I was looking for :). I was trying with "^[^\W*$]".